# Using RunWithElevatedPrivileges with ResultScriptWebPart

Tags: 2013, web-part, search, enterprise-search, runwithelevatedprivileges

We're trying to run an extended ResultScriptWebPart search with elevated privileges so that all users of the system can search and see certain information without having access to those document libraries.

I have tried using the general idea provided by the solution here ([Elevated Content Search for anonymous](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151238/elevated-content-search-for-anonymous)) but that applies to the CustomSearchWebPart which I understand is the Sharepoint 2010 implementation. I'd like to use the ResultScriptWebPart as that is the 2013 implementation and it makes hooking up refiners much easier.

The code below does go and fetch the results correctly as an admin but I have no clue how to feed it back into the UI. Accessing DataProviderJSON was pure well wishing..

```
public class ElevatedSearchResults : ResultScriptWebPart
{
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    protected override void OnBeforeSerializeToClient(BeforeSerializeToClientEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.AppManager != null)
        {
            if (this.AppManager.QueryGroups.ContainsKey(this.QueryGroupName) &&
                this.AppManager.QueryGroups[this.QueryGroupName].DataProvider != null)
            {
                this.AppManager.QueryGroups[this.QueryGroupName].DataProvider.BeforeSerializeToClient +=
                    new BeforeSerializeToClientEventHandler(EnhanceQuery);
            }
        }                                
    }

    protected virtual void EnhanceQuery(object sender, BeforeSerializeToClientEventArgs e)
    {
        // Store the current site ID in a variable, you'll need it
        Guid siteId = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;

        // Get the user token for the System Account
        // The System Account should automatically have Site Collection permissions
        SPUserToken systemAccountUserToken = SPContext.Current.Site.SystemAccount.UserToken;           

        // Elevate privileges
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
        {
            // Impersonate the System Account
            using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(siteId, systemAccountUserToken))
            {
                 //Runs at elevated privilges but doesn't return anything to SP Web
                KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(elevatedSite);
                keywordQuery.QueryText = "test";
                SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor();
                ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
                var resultTables = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
                ResultTable resultTable = resultTables.FirstOrDefault();                    
                DataTable dataTable = resultTable.Table;

                this.DataProviderJSON = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dataTable.Rows.GetEnumerator());

            }
        });       
    }
}
```

Has anyone encountered this before and can help me out? Is there another class I could extend? I used this one as it is the one used by the default Search Results web part.

Thanks

Comment: did you found a solution for the problem?
I have the same requirement to develop an elevated search results webpart. Thanks

Comment: @FourClaws I don't think we did in the end. If memory serves me right we ended up getting close to what was needed by having a Powershell script ran as an elevated user to copy all results into a library with more open permissions every so often. It would clear them all out, fetch the new ones, and write them in. I wasn't involved in writing that script so I can't offer any further detail sorry