# disable security trimming of search results only on a specific search page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, sharepoint-on-prem

**Background:**
I have created a new search page and added it to the search navigation. It only searches a specific content type. However the business requirement is to display all search items so people are aware of the vast amount of content that exists especially those items which users cant access. I have applied a series of metadata to a custom display template that describes the content via managed properties one of which is contact information.

**Problem:**
Plenty of other posts that describe how to this is addressed in 2007 and 2010 by extending the results web part. However no one has seemed to achieve this using the 2013 ResultScriptWebPart or similar? I also need to be able to use the refiners due to the large volume of items.

**Update**

Coded full trust solutions are acceptable.

I've found a [potential solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151238/elevated-content-search-for-anonymous) however this person is not using the ResultScriptWebPart. If anyone has any ideas how this would be apply to extending the ResultScriptWebPart it would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please clarify more on what is needed?

Comment: Whats the best way to disable security trimming of search results on a specific search page and not the entire search service?

Comment: Coded full trust solutions are not a problem. I've edited my post above with a possible solution however it does not apply to the ResultScriptWebPart.